# Hiding/Showing a div after a search

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to do a search form on my website and I'm not sure how to compare strings or if I'm coding it right.
I want my div to disappear when the user types the div's id in the search bar but when I try to compare the string, nothing happens.

Here's my code:

```
<body>
  <h1 class="title">News Journal</h1>
  <h6 class="motto">What's better than having multiple sources ?</h6>
  <input type="text" class="search" placeholder="Search for a website..." id="search">


  <div id="news-container">
    <p class="mostViewed">Most visited news websites...</p>
    <div class="container">

      <div class="divCNN" id="cnn">
        <a target="_blank" href="https://www.cnn.com/"><img src="https://pmcdeadline2.files.wordpress.com/2016/11/cnn-logo-2.jpg?w=892&h=598&crop=1" class="CNN"></a>
        <p class="description">CNN was founded in 1980 by American media proprietor Ted Turner as a 24-hour cable news channel. It was the first all-news television channel in the United States and CNN website has an average of 112 millions unique monthly visitors.<a target="_blank" href="https://www.cnn.com/"> Visit !</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

My Javascript:

```
function Search() {
  var string = +document.getElementById("search").value;
  if (string == "cnn") {
    document.getElementById("cnn").style.display = 'none';
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById("cnn").style.display = 'inline-block';
  }
}
document.addEventListener("keyup", Search);
</script>
```

Comment: `var string = +document.getElementById("search").value;` This tries to convert the value to a number, not a string; it'll never `== "cnn"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The preceding `+` will try to convert the value to number. If the value is not convertible to number it returns `NaN` which ultimately fails the the condition:

Change `var string = +document.getElementById("search").value;`

To

```
var string = document.getElementById("search").value;
```

```js
function Search() {
  var string = document.getElementById("search").value;
  if (string == "cnn") {
    document.getElementById("cnn").style.display = 'none';
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById("cnn").style.display = 'inline-block';
  }
}
document.addEventListener("keyup", Search);
```

```html
<h1 class="title">News Journal</h1>
<h6 class="motto">What's better than having multiple sources ?</h6>
<input type="text" class="search" placeholder="Search for a website..." id="search">


<div id="news-container">
  <p class="mostViewed">Most visited news websites...</p>
  <div class="container">

    <div class="divCNN" id="cnn">
    <a target="_blank" href="https://www.cnn.com/"><img src="https://pmcdeadline2.files.wordpress.com/2016/11/cnn-logo-2.jpg?w=892&h=598&crop=1" class="CNN"></a>
    <p class="description">CNN was founded in 1980 by American media proprietor Ted Turner as a 24-hour cable news channel. It was the first all-news television channel in the United States and CNN website has an average of 112 millions unique monthly visitors.<a target="_blank" href="https://www.cnn.com/"> Visit !</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works great thanks ! And thank you for taking the time to correct such a mistake, I'll remember not to do it again !